# Adding predefined value in mssql multiple times

Tags: sql-server, variables, parameters, insert

I have created a test table to test if this is possible my task is to add same value in multiple rows:

```
declare  @counter int
set @counter = 100

case when @counter > 0 then insert into table test values('1','2')
@count=@count - 1
```

Now this should add the values 1 and 2 in 100 rows, but it's not working. Can anyone confirm if the above code is close to solve the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 100;

WHILE @counter > 0
BEGIN
   insert into table test values('1','2');
   @count=@count - 1;
END;
```

But this is probably better because send all 100 insert at same time

**[Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/QYM28312)**

```
CREATE table test (
    f1 text,
    f2 text
);    

;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (
    SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b
)  -- 100
INSERT INTO test
    SELECT '1', '2' 
    FROM e2;

SELECT *
FROM test;
```

Comment: This works perfectly!
A second question is, whats the maximum number i can insert without risking to the database damage? 100.000 more?

Comment: first version can support any number, you only limit is `INT` second version you need to expand the CTE, with e3(n) for 1k, e4(n) for 10k and e5(n) for  100k. Your only limit should be memory, but 100k is nothing for such small query.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is just for testing you could make this super simple. I would never use code like this in production but for generating test data it is fine.

```
insert into table test values('1','2')
go 100
```

Comment: first time I see that, but seem like something is missing. I try it [**HERE**](http://rextester.com/JAQAD95831) and got an error for the `go` sintaxis.  Can you check what is missing?

Comment: I doubt it would work in there. It is an SSMS shortcut you can use. I have never seen it work anywhere outside of there. Give it a shot in SSMS and it works fine.

Comment: In fact it is even documented. :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: I see, maybe is the online version doesnt support it even when @@version say 2014, or need to specify a different separator

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH rws AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 100 1 AS dummy
    FROM sys.objects o1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
)
--INSERT INTO MyTable(id_1, id_2)
SELECT 1 AS id_1, 2 AS id_2
FROM rws
```